# iOS image stretches outside of the application

Tags: ios, image, uiimageview, resize

I have a UIImageView inside of my UIViewController. It loads an image that is 81x37 with an origin of 0x20. What I am trying to do is create that image as my background as well as a logo. What I mean by that is when I start my application I would like the image to encompass the whole screen and once I have all my data loaded and ready to display out to the user I would like to shrink it to just be an icon at the upper left hand side of the screen. I would like to say that the code for resizing works, however it seems to stretch the image and cut it off about half way. So either it is rendering outside the dimensions of the screen or only renders what it can.

Below is a code snippet of how I handle my frame resizing which is done in both my viewDidLoad and my isReady functions.

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    originalSize = CGRectMake(self.logoImage.frame.origin.x, self.logoImage.frame.origin.y, self.logoImage.frame.size.width, self.logoImage.frame.size.height);
    fullScreenSize = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height);
    [self.logoImage setFrame:fullScreenSize];
}

- (void)isReady:(BOOL)initialized
{
    if(initialized)
    {
        [self.logoImage setFrame:self.originalSize];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.logoImage setFrame:self.fullScreenSize];
    }
}
```

Comment: @Damo After you mentioned the orientation I made sure to check the fullscreen size value and lo-and-behold I needed my width == screenHeight and my height == screenWidth. There has to be a better way for the hardware to tell me the dimensions based on it's orientation rather then flipping the width and height values

Comment: you're welcome - mark me up if I helped! ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to thank Damo for answering my question. The answer is in the comments.

> Here is Damo's answer -
>
> Have you checked the fullScreenSize to see if the frame it is being
>   set to, is actually orientated correctly; i.e. "Stretch the image and
>   cut it off halfway" sounds like it has a landscape frame when it
>   should have a portrait frame (or vice versa). If that is the case look
>   for better ways to determine the frame.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just set originalSize = self.logoImage.frame and fullScreenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]?

Anyway, assuming your logoImage is an imageView, have you set the contentMode of the imageView to UIViewContentModeAspectFit, or equivalent? By default imageViews don't scale the image otherwise.

Comment: How would I set the content mode? Is this done in the IB or in code?